# Redirect to main url after removing all words etc after ? (question mark)

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

i want to redirect my visitor to main url if they come through url like this `http://domain.com?abc_3828832`.

I want that my visitor coming from that url to be redirect to `http://mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

You could try (with JavaScript):

```
if (window.location.toString().indexOf('?') > -1) {
    window.location = 'http://mydomain.com';
}
```

You could also try:

```
if (window.location.search) {
    window.location = 'http://mydomain.com';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

explode (Damien's solution) is the way to go if that's really use ever need. However, if you end up needing some twists, I suggest looking into [parse_url](http://lt.php.net/parse_url), which allows you to break down the provided URL into path, query, fragment and other segments.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as David, but has support for any protocol and will return turn the current host.  This is slightly more reusable. Nicholas Zakas recommends using the `location` object directly instead of from window because it is direct access to the properties.

```
if (location.search) {
   location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple JavaScript solution that just strips the query string and redirects the user:

```
if (window.location.search) {
    window.location = window.location.split("?")[0];
}
```

With this solution, however, the user will load the page, the JavaScript will run, and then the page will load again, which can annoy users and causes unnecessary HTTP requests.

Personally, I would use a server configuration setting, such as Apache's RewriteEngine:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^/?\?.*$    /    [R=301,L] # (Not tested, but should work)
```

Finally, if you don't have access to the server's configuration (or even a .htaccess), than you could also use a server side scripting language like PHP:

```
<?php
if (strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) {
    header("Location: /");
}
?>
```